# Is there a continuous 1-1 function on $\mathbf{R}$ which is strictly monotonic and unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous and 1-1 is always strictly monotonic and unbounded?

I think it is true. I could not find any continuous 1-1 function which is both strictly monotonic and unbounded.

Comment: @coffeemath It doesn't, because the first sentence doesn't say anything about the function being **continuous**.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking. The title and your second paragraph are not asking the same question as your first paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The question has been edited.

Answer for old version: The identity function has all these properties.

Answer to the edited version: $\arctan$ is continuous, one-to-one and bounded. However is it true that any continuous one-to-one function on $\mathbb R$ is strictly monotonic.

Comment: I agree sir. But I want to know, if the function is "always" strictly monotonic and unbounded.

Comment: @shwetha: You **said in your first sentence** that you know the answer to this.

Comment: @shwetha I think the function will be strictly monotonic. But it will not be neceserilly unbounded. A counter example is $\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$. This function has lower bound $0$ and upper bound $1$

Comment: @AsuraPath I have edited the question

Comment: @michailvazaios Thank you!

Comment: @shwetha I have now answered both versions of your question.